Detox build failing to build due to: Could not find expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin: Required by: project :
So I try to run detox build using:
detox build --configuration android.debug  

However I get this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SchedulerX'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:.
        Required by:
            project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s


Important: 'detox build' is a convenience shortcut for calling your own build command, as provided in the config file.
Failures in this build command are not the responsibility of Detox. You are responsible for maintaining this command.

Command failed: cd android && gradlew :app:assembleDebug :app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..

So under my dependencies in buildscript in my android/build.gradle, I have:
dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12')
    }

When I run this I get this error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SchedulerX'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not resolve expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12.
        Required by:
            project :
         > Could not resolve expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12.
            > Could not get resource 'https://packages.expo.dev/maven/expo/modules/expo-updates-gradle-plugin/0.24.12/expo-updates-gradle-plugin-0.24.12.pom'.
               > Could not GET 'https://packages.expo.dev/maven/expo/modules/expo-updates-gradle-plugin/0.24.12/expo-updates-gradle-plugin-0.24.12.pom'.
                  > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                     > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12.
        Required by:
            project :
         > Could not resolve expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12.
            > Could not get resource 'https://packages.expo.dev/maven/expo/modules/expo-updates-gradle-plugin/0.24.12/expo-updates-gradle-plugin-0.24.12.pom'.
               > Could not GET 'https://packages.expo.dev/maven/expo/modules/expo-updates-gradle-plugin/0.24.12/expo-updates-gradle-plugin-0.24.12.pom'.
                  > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                     > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Honestly not sure what to do at this point, I've tried researching many ways but have always ended up in a full circle to these errors.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried using:
detox build --configuration android.debug
And also adding:
classpath('expo.modules:expo-updates-gradle-plugin:0.24.12')
To my dependencies under buildscript in android/build.gradle
I can't seem to find anything on expo-updates-gradle-plugin
